# Как узнать частоту процессора

Tags: desktop

В описании моего ноутбука указано, что он двухъядерный. Тактовая частота указана - 2200 МГц. 
Это имеется ввиду частота одного ядра 2200 МГц или это частота двух ядер???

Comment: Одного ядра. Ради интереса, как вы воспользуетесь данным знанием?

Comment: "чиста так, прожать" (ц) КВН ;)

Comment: В Linux прочесть из файла /proc/cpuinfo. Это первое, что вспомнил, наверняка в каком то еще есть. См. man 5 proc

Извиняюсь, посмотрел только на заголовок и набил комментарий. Прочел текст вопроса - отвечаю:

Указана частота **каждого** ядра.

Собственно, частоты в таких описаниях *никогда не суммируют*.

Comment: сильно сомневаюсь, что там линукс ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одного. Более подробную информацию можно получить через программу cpuid.